# Cannot retrieve the principal from the client x509 certificate

Tags: java, spring, ssl, spring-security, x509

I am using Spring security in my web application and am using x509 certificates for authentication.

```
<x509 subject-principal-regex="CN=[^,]* ([^,]*),.*$" user-service- ref="MyAuthService"  />
```

Everything works fine and I can retrieve my principal and get it in my Java class. 
My trouble starts when there are infrastructure level changes on the environments (server migrations and security changes etc). I am no longer able to retrieve this information.
What I would like to do is to debug what headers / subject I am getting from the x509 certificate in order to see if I need to change the regex to retrieve the principal. 
But I don't know how to do that in spring security. How can I say log the complete header / subject from the x509 certificate at the application level. I am using spring security 3.1

Comment: Personally I'd be tempted to have a word with the infrastructure / security teams and ask them to sort out their standards properly. ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to see more details of the certificates as they are processed, it's worth noting that the Spring code to implement these filters does implement debug logging. For instance, the X509AuthenticationFilter logs the result of toString() on the X509Certificate object:

```
logger.debug("X.509 client authentication certificate:" + certs[0]);
```

Likewise, the SubjectDnX509PrincipalExtractor logs the subjectDN that it extracts from the certificate and the username that it has determined.

Given that this is the case, if you are using Log4J, you could get these in your log files by putting the following in your log4j.xml config file.

```
<logger name="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.x509">
    <level value="debug" />
</logger>
```

Other logging frameworks will have similar mechanisms for enabling debug logging of particular classes or packages.